# conflict between Laravel-websockets and ratchet/pawl packages in laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9, ratchet, incompatibility, laravel-websockets

i'm using laravel 9 with [ratchet/pawl](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl) package but when i tried to install [beyondcode/laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) it was installed but the [ratchet/pawl](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl) stopped working without any error.

please any idea ?

i tried to check all the dependencies of [beyondcode/laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) with [ratchet/pawl](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl) it works but as soon as i install [beyondcode/laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) the main package it stops without errors